# How to select from MySQL table from the least table id to to the most table id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

[phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUNDS.png)

As you can see I have 16 rows, but the `table_id` numbers are not in order of 1-16.

And I don't want to change them, I just need an SQL syntax to SELECT from the **least** number of table to the **most** number of table.

So if you know what's the syntax, please let me know, I would really appreciate that!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY` clause. Like `SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME ORDER BY 'table_id' ASC;`

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output in text format. What my experience says ,nobody likes images in SO.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` clause.
SQL query will look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME 
ORDER BY 'table_id' ASC;
```

Comment: @behhit . . . Very surprising that this would be accepted.  Usually ordering by a constant string is a no-op and does nothing useful.